# How to insert all the li content in a span for hybris

Tags: html

This is my ul-li block

```
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-content">
        <span class="list-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</span>
    </li>
    <li class="list-content">
        <span class="list-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I add this inside a hybris backoffice, the span is removed.
How can I dynamically add span tag to the ul-li content?

Comment: Is the span get removed from you ul-li from back-office?

Comment: Yes, I have to add the content of li in a span.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrapped all the li content inside the span with the class, you can inspect is and verify. Hope this will help you. Thank you.

```js
$("ul.list>li.list-content").wrapInner("<span class='list-text'></span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li class="list-content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
    </li>
    <li class="list-content">
       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I hope you are using jQuery, else please import the jQuery library files too. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this is creating span for the entire li elements in my code.

Comment: Yes, I will update the code for you then. You can select specifying the class.